# Scrolling to div without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get some functionality working on a site where by I have multiple div's with a background image that take up 100% of the viewport height (i.e 100vh)

what I am trying to achieve is smooth scrolling where as the user starts to scroll with their mouse it automatically moves to the top of the next div so their is no crossover.  This would be simple using a .scrollTop(); function but I would like this not to be bound to an on click event instead just trackpad scrolling.

I know this should be possible but as of yet I couldn't seem to see any articles regarding this.I ideally would like to achieve this without the need for hardcoding each div if possible so the code is somewhat expandable (maybe if it checked for mydiv + value and did a count - mydiv1 mydiv2 ext )

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are aware of the onscroll event? 
Just use "
document.getElementById('divElem').scrollIntoView();
"
when onscroll event happens, and as divElem use the name of the next div, read more about onscroll, it allows you to check actuall scroll position in comparison with the last scroll position so you can determine if it goes up or down

Comment: To continue @Karol's comment - on scroll, find the scrolltop (i.e., distance from the top of the document to the view) - if it is more than 1x vh, scroll to the top of the second div, if it is 2x vh, scroll to the third div, etc. This should also sort scrolling up, not just down.

Comment: Should this only apply for mousehweel scrolling or touch scrolling on mobile devices aswell?

Comment: document.getElementById('divElem').scrollIntoView(); did this using .clientHeight for the viewport height, thanks guys still fumbling my way around js.